# Is there any way to force blank Macbook Pro 2011 to use Intel Graphics all the time?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, macbook-pro, intel-graphics, amd-graphics-card

Macbook Pro 2011 (15-inch) AMD Graphics is dead and stuck on white screen, HDD is formatted, Windows 10 installed, is there any way to force it to use Intel Graphics all the time through windows or maybe CMD?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267581/gpu-problem-boot-hangs-on-grey-screen

Comment: @Tetsujin unfortunately cannot access to boot into Single User Recovery with CMD + R + S, it won't work.